# Reducing code duplication and replacing #define with templates

Tags: c++, templates

I have code like this:

```
#define defaultOnTimer(N, X) \
 if (Timers.N) Timers.N --; \
 if (!Timers.N) S.X = D.X; \

defaultOnTimer(t1, sig1); 
defaultOnTimer(t2, sig2); 
defaultOnTimer(t3, sig3); 
defaultOnTimer(t4, sig4);
```

Although this works, I'm wondering if it would be possible to use a C++ template for the same job. 'defaultOnTimer' may be extended in the future to additional work, so I don't want to just duplicate it as many times as needed and then having to find and modify each one.

Or is this just an overly complex job and I should just stick with the #define ?

Note that S.X could be any type.

Comment: No templates cannot do exactly that. They can do something similar if you are willing to change the interface slightly (and S is the same type as D).

Answer (score 0):

It looks terrible but it works somehow:

```
template<typename A, size_t N, typename B, size_t X>
void onTimer()
{
    A& n = *(A*)(&Timers + N);
    if (n)
    {
        --n;
    }
    if (!n)
    {
        *(B*)(&S + X) = *(B*)(&D + X);
    }
}
```

here is an example:

```
struct Timer
{
    int t1, t2, t3, t4;
};
struct Sig
{
    char sig1, sig2, sig3, sig4;
};

Sig S, D;
Timer Timers;

void a()
{    
    onTimer<int, offsetof(Timer, t1), char, offsetof(Sig, sig1)>();
}
```

But `D`, `S` and `Timers` should be global variables. You can avoid this by passing them as function arguments:

```
template<typename A, size_t N, typename B, size_t X>
void onTimer(Timer* timer, Sig* sigS, Sig* sigD)
{
    A& n = *(A*)(timer + N);
    if (n)
    {
        --n;
    }
    if (!n)
    {
        *(B*)(sigS + X) = *(B*)(sigD + X);
    }
}

void a()
{    
    Sig S, D;
    Timer Timers;
    onTimer<int, offsetof(Timer, t1), char, offsetof(Sig, sig1)>(&Timers, &S, &D);
}
```

I guess this answers your question but it is still a cranky solution